# How to delete on cascade with when the database has not this set?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, cascading-deletes

I have a SQL Server database that has two tables with a 1:N relationship. In the relationship I have set the on delete, do nothing, because in general I want to control this in the logic business, I mean, in my repository.

So in my repository I get the rows that I need to delete from both tables, and in theory I get all the parents rows of the main table that are parents of the rows of the child table. So I would have no problems.

But I know that when I do `saveChanges`, EF not ensure the order of the deletings, so it is possible that try to delete a parent before deleting all the childs, so this is the problem.

So my quesetion is if there is any way to configure the `dbContext`, the relation of both entities to delete the rows without this problem?

My code is:

```
using(MyEntities myDbContext = new myEntities())
{
    //Here I could configure myDbContext to perform a correct deleting?

    //code to get the rows to delete

    myDbContext.SaveChanges(); //here is the error.
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to delete the parent call SaveChanges and then delete the children and call SaveChanges again?

Comment: Yes, this way works, but I would like to avoid two roundtrips to the database to delete few records. I am thinking to delegate the deleting to the database using triggers and use the repository only for set values and the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity should contain a navigation property of the entity/table that it's related to. Assuming table a was the parent table, you would then delete all the record(s) in the navigation property that points to the child table/table b. Then you would delete the record(s) from table a. Then call myDbContext.SaveChanges() and EF would take care of all the cascade on delete stuff for you.